# PHP Internal Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, symbols, internals

I need to access the PHP internal representation of the `$_GET` and `$_POST` arrays inside of my function for a particular page request. Is there a PHP internal representation of these arrays? Like for example `$_GLOBAL` is a representation of the internal array EG[Symbol_Table]. Otherwise is there any way to identify and access the GET and POST variables inside the symbol table and extract them?

In short I need all the variables that I would get from the `$_POST` and `$_GET` arrays but inside the Zend Engine. I am developing an extension that has a function with the format (input parameters, page) where the input parameters are all the variables declared by the php page. Is there any way to access this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question, but have you tried `print_r()`? eg. `print_r($_POST)` will print everything inside that object/array

Comment: Are you writing this in C? Might be best if you specify exactly what you're doing as people are obviously getting confused.

Comment: Thanks...I added some more info in the answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're `PG(http_globals)[TRACK_VARS_GET]` and `PG(http_globals)[TRACK_VARS_POST]` respectively.

Comment: Yes I am writing the extension in C inside the zend engine. Heres the overview of what I need to do.

I need to access all the variables declared inside a single php page request and send those along with the page name to another function that does some processing on the input parameters.

Comment: @user890928 Ok, well there's six elements in http_globals and you should find everything you need in there. Each one is an array zval.

Comment: Will those give me access to the get and post variables inside C inside a particular page? Also is there any way to restrict these variables to a single page request? I mean get only the variables from a single page and not others?

Comment: Sorry my network timed out and I posted an old reply after your most recent one. Thanks for the help...i'll look up that array.

Comment: @user890928 Yes they only represent a single page request.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! It really helped me a LOT!

Is there some zend api function to access this array?

Comment: @user890928 You're welcome :) Since they're array zvals you can use the zend_hash API where the hash is for example, `Z_ARRVAL_P(PG(http_globals)[TRACK_VARS_GET])`.

Answer (score 0):

In the newer version (I assume after 5.3), you have to use stream "php://input" to access GET or POST data.

You can look into the implementation of file_get_contents function in php to see how to open and read a stream.